# Angular (HTTP): Two select fields should update each other, but only one does

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, forms, input

I have two select input fields in my HTML view. When I click on the first one, a JSON request will take place and will respond me some ID's which I wanna use later but already for the next input. The second input field takes the selected ID from the first input and starts another API request. Finally it'll be display in `let appointmentDate of appointmentDates` So far so good.

But one thing is not satisfying. **When the user selects the `selectedAppointmentTypeId` but switches the `selectedAppointmentLocation` select field, my response `appointmentDates` doesn't get updated**.

How can I make them to work together?

This is my HTML view:

```
<select 
  type="appointmentLocation" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedAppointmentLocation" 
  (ngModelChange)="onChangeLocation($event)">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let appointmentLocation of appointmentLocations" 
    [ngValue]="appointmentLocation.id">
    {{appointmentLocation.name}}
  </option>
</select>
{{selectedAppointmentLocation}}

<select 
  type="appointmentType" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedAppointmentTypeId" 
  (ngModelChange)="onChangeTypeId($event)">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let appointmentType of appointmentTypes | filter:false" 
    [ngValue]="appointmentType.id">
    {{appointmentType.name}}
  </option>
</select>
{{selectedAppointmentTypeId}}

<span 
  *ngFor="let appointmentDate of appointmentDates">
  {{appointmentDate.date}}
</span>
```

This is my component.ts:

```
private appointmentLocations: Array < object > = [];
private appointmentTypes: Array < object > = [];
private appointmentDates: Array < object > = [];
selectedAppointmentTypeId: string;
selectedAppointmentLocation: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
}

onChangeLocation(LocationId) {
  console.log(LocationId);
  this.selectedAppointmentLocation = LocationId;
}

onChangeTypeId(TypeId) {
  console.log(TypeId);
  this.selectedAppointmentTypeId = TypeId;
  this.apiService
    .getAppointmentDatesById(
      this.selectedAppointmentTypeId,
      this.selectedAppointmentLocation
    )
    .subscribe((data: Array < object > ) => {
      this.appointmentDates = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
}

public getData() {
  this.apiService
    .getAppointmentLocations()
    .subscribe((data: Array < object > ) => {
      this.appointmentLocations = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  this.apiService.getAppointmentTypes().subscribe((data: Array < object > ) => {
    this.appointmentTypes = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

This is my API.service:

```
getAppointmentDatesById(
  selectedAppointmentTypeId,
  selectedAppointmentLocation
) {
  return this.httpClient.get(
    `${this.API_URL}/availability/dates/${selectedAppointmentTypeId}/2018-09/${selectedAppointmentLocation}`
  );
}
```

Comment: Please consider creating a StackBlitz if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try forcibly re-running the second selection if something has been selected already:

```js
onChangeLocation(LocationId) {
  console.log(LocationId);
  this.selectedAppointmentLocation = LocationId;
  // check if a value exists and use it
  if(this.selectedAppointmentTypeId) {
    this.onChangeTypeId(this.selectedAppointmentTypeId);
  }
}
```

since you're not actually changing the second select value, it wil not re-run your change function without you specifically requesting it.